# What can make a motor increase acceleration instead of decreased acceleration when i removed a spark plug wire upon testing?

Tags: troubleshooting

on our 1982 Ford F100 Pickup, Never seen this one before...
So Whatin the world can make a motor increase acceleration , instead of decreased acceleration when i removed a spark plug wire upon testing ?

Comment: Presumably you mean engine speed, not acceleration?

Comment: Does the engine have an electronically controlled idle speed control valve?

Comment: @handyhowie on a 1982 pickup I'd be amazed if it had electronic anything - even spark plugs were steam powered back then

Comment: @CaiusJard My 1985 Ford Granada 2.8 had EFI, but maybe 1982 is a bit early.

Comment: First fuel injection was on a production car in 1955 Mercedes... But on Fix Or Repair Daily - just a bit later...

Comment: @SolarMike  That wouldn't have been EFI though.  Do you know which production car had the first EFI?

Comment: @HandyHowie A quick google gives Bosch 1967 on a VolksWagen 1600... amazing what a google search gives, see https://www.autonews.com/article/20040823/SUB/408230807/electronic-fuel-injection-a-history-lesson  But not too sure about some of the "theory" given by the writer...

Comment: Are you sure all of the plug leads are on the correct plugs?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which engine you have, but all are carb as far as I can tell.

Most have either a mechanical (vaccuum) or electronic altitude/idle speed throttle compensation system.  It stands to reason that this system would compensate for the drop in idle speed due to disabling one cylinder.

Comment: I meant to ask what makes the motor idle ( higher ) instead of idle dropping when testing firing. Never saw this happen before. When I touch the top of plugs wires with tester the engine idle drops as should except for one plug , when I touch it with tester the stupid engine idles real high, I don't get it.

Comment: My motor is a 302,

Comment: 1982 Ford F 100,

Comment: Not sure what kind of tester you have - mine measures the electromagnetic field with induction in a non-contact proble and calculates estimated spark voltage - and at no time does it affect idle speed, on any engine or ignition system - distributor, COP, or otherwise.